# PHP Objects... Why when instantiating a class within a class is the properties not visible to other functions?

Tags: php, oop

I've looked around a lot for help on this. I realise this is probably more to do with the way I am using objects (I'm new to OO PHP) but it's really bugging me. Here is a massively simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php
class Show_message {
    public $message_instance = ""; //ensure Message object variable is visible
    function __construct() {
    //do nothing
    }
    function display_message() {
        $message_instance = new Message(); //instatiate Message object
        echo $message_instance->message . " : in display_message function <br>"; //works
    }
    function display_again() {
        echo $message_instance->message . " : in display_again function <br>"; //does not work
    }
}
class Message {
    public $message = ""; //ensure $this->message variable is visible?
    function __construct() {
        $this->message = "Hello world"; //make message
    }
}
$instance = new Show_message(); //instatiate Show_message object
$instance->display_message(); //method to create instance and display message
$instance->display_again(); //method to display message again
?>
```

Why is the `$message_instance->message` not visible to the `display_again()` function?

Comment: What do you mean `$message->instance` ? There isn't a property called that!

Comment: `$message_instance` is a function local variable, `$this->message_instance` is an object member variable.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a valid question, maybe one with an easy answer but still a valid and well written question. I am sure when everyone was learning a question like this with a valid answer would have been nice to study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$this->`, otherwise you are storing the `Message` object locally to the function, not to the class instance.

```
$this->message_instance = new Message();
```

and `$this->message_instance` everywhere you are doing `$message_instance`.

Comment: Thankyou! I didn't realise you could do this `$this->message_instance->message`

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/Hi0fs4)**

Because you are setting a `local` variable inside the function, you must use `$this` to access object properties.

```
<?php
class Show_message {
    public $message_instance = ""; //ensure Message object variable is visible
    function __construct() {
        $this->message_instance = new Message();
    }
    function display_message() {
         //instatiate Message object
        echo $this->message_instance->message . " : in display_message function <br>";
    }
    function display_again() {
        echo $this->message_instance->message . " : in display_again function <br>";
    }
}
class Message {
    public $message = ""; //ensure $this->message variable is visible?
    function __construct() {
        $this->message = "Hello world"; //make message
    }
}
$instance = new Show_message(); //instatiate Show_message object
$instance->display_message(); //method to create instance and display message
$instance->display_again(); //method to display message again
?>
```